# Angular - change the colour of selected mat-icons within a mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, selected, mat-tab, mat-icon

i have several tabs with different icons each, both from angular materials. if i change the colour of the icons via ::ng-deep it works, but it does not change the colour anymore when it is selected anymore.

```
::ng-deep .mat-icon {
    color: var(--theme-color3);
}

::ng-deep .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active {
  color: var(--theme-color1) !important;
}
```

Any idea how I could change the icons colour, when selected?